# Read excel file into database using mvc3 and stored procedure and without using any driver(Ace/Jet) and without EPPlus dlls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a requirement to upload and read an excel file into the database using a stored procedure but i can not use any external dlls like EPPlus or drivers like Jet/Ace. Can anyone help me to do this? I searched on so many sites but none met my requirements. This should be implemented in MVC 3. I have created the view. And the Browse option is working fine. All i need to know is how to upload and read.

Comment: is oledb allowed? If it's allowed follow this link http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-Excel-file-using-OLEDB-Data-Provider-in-C-Net.aspx . And one thing if you will deploy your app later on another server with no microsoft installed then you need to install access database engine to create connection to your excel file

Comment: no it is also not allowed

Comment: that was sad bro, better resign and hunt pokemons :D, Or convert your excel to another readable format like (e.g csv, xml) to be able to read the contents

Comment: If you can't use any libraries then you have to do everything yourself. In the end it's not that difficult: unzip the file and read the xml.
This page might give you some information to get understand the file format better: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278328.aspx